# React Native - IOS Platform — How to bring App in focus / foreground from background on receiving Push Notification

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-push-notifications, background-foreground

I am using OneSignal to send Push Notifications to my React Native App. On receiving notification I bring up a Custom React Native screen to take some input from User.

I followed the instructions mentioned here:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup

The above two guides mainly explains how to Initialize OneSignal, setup notification listeners and other required Native settings.

After the above configuration I am able to send Notification (and bring up the Custom Screen) to App on iPhone but only if App is in Foreground. The App was not receiving notification if in Background.

Then I followed the below article by Oleg Kalyta and configured:

https://hackernoon.com/complete-guide-receive-push-notifications-in-react-native-ios-app-38b1ec5b1b15

It explains how to configure PushNotificationIOS RN package and setup some more functions and listeners. Though I don’t quite understand why I need these functions if I have already configured OneSignal listeners. And how it will impact on my App’s performance with too many listeners.

After this configuration I am able to receive notification (it comes at top of iPhone and goes away after 2-3 seconds) even if the App is in Background. But it does not bring my App in Focus and does not show Custom screen.

I am looking for help to resolve the issue and show the Custom screen if App is in Background and it receives notification.

Interestingly the OneSignal listeners are getting called and I am also able to see the sent data in the logs but I am not sure how to bring up the IOS App in focus.

In Android I am able to even unlock the phone and bring the App in focus on receiving notification. I have written some Android Native code using Android PowerManager and WindowManager packages. I am calling this native code from my React Native OneSignal listener to Wake up the phone and bring the App in focus and display the custom screen.

The same thing I am trying to achieve in IOS.

Please can anyone help. I have gone through lot of articles on Net but I am not able to find any solution.

Comment: If the AP is in the background then the user needs to tap on the notification to bring your app back to the foreground.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I checked an existing App, it plays a continuous ring tone and shows notification on locked screen. If phone is unlocked and App is in Background then it plays continuous ring tone and the notification slides from top 2 times. I am trying to figure out at least play ring tone continuously to let User alert. I am using InCall Manager RN library to play ring tone on Custom screen. I am calling the same function if App is in Background but the ring is not coming. Please can guide. Many thanks for your help.